Can't access ports when using network_mode=host
I am trying to deploy a stack for home assistant. When setting the port 8123 manually, localhost:8123 loads home asisstant perfectly. But when trying to use network_mode=host (which is needed for homekit integration) it won't load anymore. Any ideas?
I am using linux btw, I know network_mode=host wont work in windows or mac.

Host networking disables several Docker networking features, including published ports, and it's rarely a best-practice configuration.  If docker run -p 8123:8123 works for you, I'd keep using it, with Docker's standard networking setup and not host networking.

("network_mode=host wont work" is a property of Docker Desktop and other similar VM-based setups, not necessarily the host OS.  If you're using Docker Desktop on Linux, you have a hidden Linux VM, and host networking doesn't work in the same way it doesn't work on MacOS or Windows hosts.)

It turns out it was docker desktop. Uninstalling it and using normal docker seems to have worked. Thank you!
